# Unique id with some constraints in java

Tags: java, mysql, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

I have been searching for a solution to generate unique id and I could not find anything matching with my requirements. The problem is:

I have a database table "Transaction" which has all the transactions performed by various "Vendors". So, the transactionId is unique for a specific vendor. Till now I used to generate transactionId using Random Alphanumeric API in java for a unique value. So far good. Now, we got a requirement from a Vendor to generate id's starting from 1 till 999999 and after it reaches upper limit we need to reset it to 1. For this logic I need an auto increment on transaction id specific to this vendor. I cannot utilize database auto-increment as its not on whole column.

One solution that I have right now is - to add a trigger on that table insert function and update the record's transaction id value by auto incrementing it if it is for that specific vendor.

I am not really happy with this solution and looking for any other ideas through java code which might make it easier and does not impact performance (ex : like using synchronization). This particular logic is for a web application where multiple users will perform transactions at the same time. Any suggestions will really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try this ? https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @Proxytype - If u meant to go through ROWID, it is not much helpful. I need a reset on the value once it reaches upper limit. Let me know if I am missing something. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think, your mileage may vary. You can create a table called say 'vendor_transaction' with two fields vendor_name and transaction_id. Idea is to maintain current_transaction_id for vendors in this table. Each vendor will have one entry in this table and that will give you the current transaction_id for that vendor.

Now write a service/utility to get the transaction_id for a given vendor in an atomic operation. ie. provide an interface like increment_and_get(vendor_name) which will increment the current transaction id and return the value in a transaction. Also the utility/can handle the overflow case when the transaction id is at 999999.

Hope this will give you some idea.

Comment: This is a good idea, Any ideas about how to lock this particular method? Can use @ Transactional on my method and that is sufficient?